# How to make normal borders of areas in Inkscape?

Tags: html, inkscape

I'm making in interactive map of Russia. I need to select its regions on the picture for I can work with them. But it works incorrectly. When I try to select first region it's okay. But then I try to select another adjacent region just making new levers to existing contours. After I close the path, I want this region to become the full second area in the picture. But when I try to highlight this area, it turns out that Inkscape doesn't count this as an area. It believes that this is just a new open line. It turns out that a new area has not formed.[In the picture you can see that the boundaries of the area are not highlighted everywhere, therefore the area remains open (it is not an area at all, it is a piece of a broken line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FT2g.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong kind of object for your work. What you need is indeed a set of closed paths, but what you have is the borders only.

The easiest way to convert one into the other is to:

- make sure all the separate borders touch at their ends
- select all the separate borders
- Path > Combine them into a single path
- put a large rectangle below this combined path that covers the full area below
- select both
- Path > Division

Now you should have the lines cut through the rectangle.
Remove the parts you do not need, and close any gaps that are left.